# How to compare two DataTables with common values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two datatable dt1 and st2.

dt1 consists of `PorductId` `ProductName` `FilePath`:

```
1   Product1   c:\
2   Product2   c:\
3   Product3   c:\
4   Product4   c:\
```

dt2 consists of `ProductName` `DateofDelivery`:

```
Product2   2016-01-03
Product3   2016-03-02
Product5   2016-02-03
Product7   2014-09-01
```

I need to return all rows from dt2 where the ProductName of dt2 is in dt1 the result should be:

```
Product2   2016-01-03
Product3   2016-03-02
```

I've tried this, but its not working:

```
var matched = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() 
    on table1.Field<string>("ProductName") equals table2.Field<string>("ProductName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Really what you want to do is filter the second Datatable by the first, I would use a where instead of a join, the example below should replicate what your trying to do:

```
//Assemble the DataTables mentioned in your question
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));

dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Product1", "c:\\");
dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Product2", "c:\\");
dt1.Rows.Add(3, "Product3", "c:\\");
dt1.Rows.Add(4, "Product4", "c:\\");

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
dt2.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));

dt2.Rows.Add("Product2", "2016-01-03");
dt2.Rows.Add("Product3", "2016-01-04");
dt2.Rows.Add("Product5", "2016-01-05");
dt2.Rows.Add("Product7", "2016-01-06");

//Get the values from dt1 to filter by
var filter = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(b => b.Field<string>("ProductName")).ToList();

//Then filter the second list by the ProductName of the first list
var matched = dt2.AsEnumerable().Where(a => filter.Contains(a.Field<string>("ProductName")))
.ToList();
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

try test this code

```
var dtproducts = dt1.Rows.Select(x => [ProductName]).ToArray();

var matches = (from System.Data.DataRow product in st1.Rows
                where dtproducts.Contains(product["ProductName"])
                select product).ToList();
```