# How to create new DataTable left-joining two in-memory Datatables (no data connection involved)?

Tags: .net, linq, join, datatable

Suppose I have 2 DataTable objects, named DT1 and DT2:

DT1:

```
ID  Name         Email
-----------------------------------
1   John Doe     johndoe@foo.com
2   Richard Roe  ricroe@roeco.com
3   Mary Moe     mm2357@xmail.com
```

DT2:

```
ID  Active  Last_Contact
------------------------
1   True    12/05/2015
3   False   07/23/2014
```

I'd like to perform an operation using only these two in-memory datatables (without new queries against database) and create a new datatable such as this:

DTjoin:

```
ID  Name         Email             Active  Last_Contact
-------------------------------------------------------
1   John Doe     johndoe@foo.com   True    12/05/2015
2   Richard Roe  ricroe@roeco.com  
3   Mary Moe     mm2357@xmail.com  False   07/23/2014
```

Is there a straightforward way to achieve that to any pair of tables providing no more data than it would take to perform a SQL LEFT JOIN? That is, tables involved, relation-on-equality field and output fields?

Is there any Linq approach best suited for datatables?

Thank you very much to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable` has a built-in method to do that, you may like it:

```
dt1.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt1.Columns[0] };
dt2.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt2.Columns[0] };

dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

This gives the result you want to achieve, but note that it overwrites `dt1`.

Comment: Yes, I like it :-) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36581313/2912011). It should be relatively straight forward to join the two tables. I would simply convert both into anonymous types and then use the LINQ Join operator to join them([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)), It would look something like the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20760794/2912011).

Hope that's enough information, it should be relatively easy to adapt the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20760794/2912011) answer to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the examples that were suggested and other sources, I decided to write my own extension function, for I wanted something that stored the result of the join in a DataTable.

It is pretty raw and far from error-safe, I think, therefore I welcome anyone's effort of debugging and improving it:

```
<Extension()> _
Function JoinOnEquality(datatable0 As DataTable,
                        datatable1 As DataTable,
                        relationkey As String,
                        foreignkey As String,
                        Optional sourcecolumns As String() = Nothing,
                        Optional foreigncolumns As String() = Nothing
                        ) As DataTable
    Dim dtjoin As New DataTable
    If sourcecolumns Is Nothing Then
        sourcecolumns = datatable0.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).Select(
            Function(dc) dc.ColumnName
            ).ToArray
    End If
    For Each scolumn In sourcecolumns
        dtjoin.Columns.Add(
            datatable0.Columns(scolumn).ColumnName,
            datatable0.Columns(scolumn).DataType)
    Next
    If foreigncolumns Is Nothing Then
        foreigncolumns = datatable1.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).Select(
            Function(dc) dc.ColumnName
            ).Except(sourcecolumns).ToArray
    End If
    For Each fcolumn In foreigncolumns
        dtjoin.Columns.Add(
            datatable1.Columns(fcolumn).ColumnName,
            datatable1.Columns(fcolumn).DataType)
    Next
    Dim joinrow, foreignrow As DataRow
    For Each sourcerow In datatable0.Select
        For Each foreignrow In datatable1.Select.Where(
            Function(dr) Equals(sourcerow(relationkey), dr(foreignkey))
            ).DefaultIfEmpty(datatable1.NewRow)
            joinrow = dtjoin.NewRow
            For Each scolumn In sourcecolumns
                joinrow(scolumn) = sourcerow(scolumn)
            Next
            For Each fcolumn In foreigncolumns
                joinrow(fcolumn) = foreignrow(fcolumn)
            Next
            dtjoin.Rows.Add(joinrow)
        Next
    Next
    Return dtjoin
End Function
```